# Why does Asp.net 5 (DNX) w3wp.exe crash on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-core, dnx

My team's Asp.net 5 web app (1.0.0-rc1-update1) is getting w3wp.exe crashes on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2) both when restarting IIS and intermittently during normal operation of two load balanced instances.

It seems to be the same error as in the following github issue.  The error and fault info are nearly identical:
https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/35

```
'w3wp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x6f54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x000000007717298A (ntdll.dll) in w3wp.exe: 0xC000070A: Status 0x (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFFC0000008, 0x00000000000002F8, 0x00000000003E59F0, 0x000000000038A280, 0x000007FEF4CF88F4).

Exception thrown at 0x000007FEF4CF88F4 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000007FEF4CF88F4.

Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEF4CF88F4 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000007FEF4CF88F4.

The program '[4540] w3wp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This issue does not appear for us on IIS 8 with Windows 2012 R2.  It seems to be an underlying HttpPlatformHandler or DNX stability issue with IIS 7.5 vs 8.

Are others seeing this problem? Has anyone seen an easier workaround for this issue than upgrading the windows/iis version?  It does not seem to be deterministically triggered by our application code.  The github issue has not been updated for some time and unfortunately we may not be equipped to do crash dump analysis or process debugging.

---

Re: HttpPlatform Log

I turned on the HttpPlatform log using the webconfig setting:

```
<httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
```

The startup is logged as usual on initialization, but doesn't log an error when the crash is reproduced:

```
Hosting environment: XXXXXX
Now listening on: http://localhost:XXXX
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler was once IIS 8+ only, so I guess the hack they use to support IIS 7.5 is not quite reliable yet. You will have to report to Microsoft and see if they can provide an update. In this case leave a comment on GitHub to tell that you hit a similar issue and they should take some action if more and more users report it.

Comment: I agree with Lex Li, but just for the sake of completeness, could you add the following to the httpPlatform tag in your web.config: stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log"? Still should output a log file. And post the contents here?

Comment: Updated with results from turning on the httpPlatform log

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as  "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: Yes, this should probably be closed as it will not be fixed in the pre-Core versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it's coming from a bug in aspnetcore.dll (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule) occuring on a few given combination of Windows (7 for instance) & IIS (7.5 for instance). You can find this module somewhere in your c:\windows\systemXXX.

When I get the lastest from GitHub dev branch, it's fixed for me.
I believe the fix lies in the changelist: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/pull/59

This version is not officially delivered yet and is not packaged in the 7.1.1971 version of the DLL which is the latest as of now.

Comment: This has been released in the following version: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/releases/tag/1.0.1972 (product version is 7.1.1972). I'm waiting for a new .Net Core Runtime including this new version.